# Removing end of a line after calling a void function

Tags: c++

I have a void function that recursively prints an AVL tree in order, using a comma and a space between every key.

After the void function is called, I want to remove the last comma and space, but I am not sure how. I tried doing `std::cout << '\b' << '\b'`, but it doesn't do anything.

What I'm trying is something like:

```cpp
void printInoder(root){
    InorderHelper(root);
    cout << '\b' << '\b' << endl;
}
```

Comment: The `\b` will only work if your terminal supports it. In some terminals, it might just move the cursor backward instead of erasing anything.

Comment: user17005485 Did the answer help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

The name *backspace* is a bit misleading. It doesn't print a space.

If the output ends with `,`  you probably want `std::cout << "\b\b \b\n";`. That is, step two steps back, print a space over the `,` and then step one step back. Since you do a newline last, the last `\b` can be omitted.

```
std::cout << "\b\b \n";
```

It would probably be better to fix it at the source and *not* print the characters you want to erase at all.